# standard deviation formula --population or sample

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

if given a set of data say 10 numbers, which one should we use standard deviation or sample standard deviation.there is no mention of sample or population in the problem.[image]

Comment: This is going to come down to when you’ve learned to use the formula for population standard deviation...so when did you learn to use that formula?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be a subjective one, but I think since there is no mention of *sample* in the question, it's more likely for it to refer to the population statistics. So, you'll divide by $n$, instead of $n-1$ as done in sample standard deviation formula.

Comment: My first reaction was also to use sample standard deviation, but now I wonder if we should consider those women to be the population of starting five on the team.

Comment: Now, I'm thinking the otherwise as well. Adding tags for increasing the chance of this q/a to be reviewed by others.